# Xdebug PhpStorm: debugging scripts started with exec("php index.php")

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to add debugging to an old project that uses `exec()` to start a new session asynchronously from within another PHP script:

```
exec("php /var/www/html/validata/index.php",$result)
```

The normal PHP script is fully debugable with Xdebug but the script started with the exec command isn't because it can't map from `file:///var/www/html/index.php` to a local file location since it's started within CLI shell. The session started this way does trigger the debugger but can't find the file locally:

```
Cannot find file '/var/www/html/validata/index.php' locally.
To fix it set server name by environment variable PHP_IDE_CONFIG and restart debug session.
```

I've followed the instructions to add the `PHP_IDE_CONFIG` to the env. I've also added this to the server with 127.0.0.1 replaced with the desktop PC IP address (server is running in a docker container):

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_enable=1 remote_mode=req remote_port=9000 remote_host=127.0.0.1 remote_connect_back=0"
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

**Solution:**

Use the cli interpreter set to the docker container (in settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > CLI interpreter, add new, select docker and point it to the php binary) so that a debug session can be started with a new debugging configuration. I've copied the arguments from the exec command into the new configuration and it can now fully debug the script. I have to prepare a database table to make it fully testable but this is a working solution for me.

Thanks for all the replies!

Comment: 1) Do you have that file locally? 2) If you do -- add the path mapping so that IDE can find it (`Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers`)

Comment: That doesn't work as it can't mapp file:///path to my local repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue about the wrong php.ini file being loaded by specifying it in the command line:

```
exec("php -c " . escapeshellarg(php_ini_loaded_file()) .
    " /var/www/html/validata/index.php",$result);
```

Though I doubt that would make much of a difference as far as xdebug is concerned.

I think a better solution would be to just `require` the file, which would cause xdebug to not become lost when you fork a new process.

```
require_once "/var/www/html/validata/index.php";
```

Comment: It uses arguments to refer to some different modules etc so a require looses that unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a mistake how to refer to the server in PHP_IDE_CONFIG:
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=SomeName"
should be run in the container where php runs, and SomeName should exactly match what is in PHPStorm/IntelliJ Settings > Languages & Frameworks > php > Servers > Name (not host). It's not a fqdn, just whatever is in the name field.